# GraphVIZ edges bent at 90 degrees

Tags: graphviz

I am able to draw the nodes and edges for a network diagram using GraphVIZ. But that is not appealing. How can I make the edges/connectors bent at right angle like T, L shaped edges.

Answer (score 22):

I think adding

```
graph [splines=ortho]
```

Will do what you want.

http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:splines

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS, with GraphVIZ version 2.26.3. Is there any limitation for this version?

Comment: Did any one install GraphViz Version 2.38 ( OR any thing later 2.26 version) on UBUNTU?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. It is actually a graph attribute, not an edge attribute. Updating answer. It works for me on Ubuntu with GraphVIZ v2.26.3.

Comment: Can I do that only when the edge touches the node and curve the rest?